# Pausing a UIView's key frame animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I'm currently creating a loading bar that I would like to pause and reverse if a specific action is taken.

I have the following code below that animates one view in another. How would I go about pausing this animation and applying another animation on the CURRENT frame at that point in time for the animated object. I would like to be able to animate this bar down to the 0 width mark at any given time within the current animation.

```
-(void)animateProgressBar
{
    CGRect endingFrame = self.frame;

    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:self.time delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            self.loadingBar.frame = endingFrame;
        }];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"TADA");
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to start a new animation from where this one is now, just start the new animation using the the `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` option (or if just doing `animateWithDuration`, use `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState`).

Comment: Is there any way I can detect the percentage of completion to the animation? I only want to reverse it, if it hasn't been finished. <edit> I'll just store a property in the completion block unless there's a way I can get the exact percentage. Thank you soo much for the help.

Comment: You can grab the `presentationLayer` (as Greg pointed out) and look at the position contained there to figure out the percent complete, but do you really need to do that? Just initiate the reversing animation with the `...FromCurrentState` option, and it should gracefully reverse it without any extra work. The only reason you'd need the percent complete if you wanted to change the duration of the reversing animation, but on reasonably fast animations, that's really not needed.

Comment: If the loading bar is 80% completed, I don't want the animation cancelled.. so unfortunately I do. I will try out what you and Greg have mentioned and see if that gives me what I desire. Thank you guys

Comment: @TheGamingArt Two simple options: 1. Grab the `frame` from the `presentationLayer` and use that to calculate the percent of the distance covered; or 2. Store a `CFAbsoluteTime` variable with the start time, `animationStartTime` of the last animation as determined by `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()`, and just see how much time has elapsed (e.g. `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - self.animationStartTime`), and use that to determine whether you think you can reverse it or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can import QuartzCore framework, add

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

And you can remove existing animation by calling:

```
[self.loadingBar.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

After that you can start new animation.
If you want to pause it you have to get reference to the current animation:

```
CALayer *currentLayer = self.loadingBar.layer.presentationLayer;
```

And you have to save it:

```
self.loadingBar.layer.transform = currentLayer.transform;
```

You can do it in another [UIView animateWith..... method.

Comment: nah, this is too much working considering keyframe animations are made to replace all of these nuances. Also, if you removeAll the animations in the middle of a keyframe animation... it resets it's state as if the animation hasn't happened at all. I've already tried using that to my advantage.

Comment: If you save currentLayer first and removeAllAnimations after that you can call layer.transform = currentLayer.transform and you should save your animation state.

Comment: I will give that a shot (which I thought I did, but I probably did something wrong XD). Thank you guys again for the assistance.